# Set Maya Image Plane Attr "Image Number" to expression "=frame" through python

Tags: python, camera, maya, setattr

I'm trying to set the attribute "Image Number" to the expression "=frame" through python. Currently I've tried

```
cmds.setAttr(myImagePlane+".ufe", 1)
cmds.setAttr(myImagePlane+".fe", '=frame')
```

Which doesn't work as .fe only takes integers. From maya documentation I don't see an attribute directly for image number. How can I get around this without the user having to manually create the expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create an expression through cmds.expression

```
cmds.expression(o=myImagePlane, s='{}.fe = frame;'.format(myImagePlane))
```